# Add To Cart link on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, e-commerce

I have some code in my e-shop. I would like to change normal link to jquery. I would like to my link "add to cart"  will be performed in the background.

This is code:

```
  <a 
                    rel="?{=result.tempVariant.id}" 
                    class="addToCart greenBtn"
                    href="${system.baseUrl}#{uri:koszyk/}AddVariant/?{=result.tempVariant.id}?{if  system.postData.requestPostData.creatorTemplate}?creatorTemplate=?{=system.postData.requestPostData.creatorTemplate}?{endif}">
                    #{add to cart}
                </a>
```

When I click Add To Cart link in my shop, item will be added to cart, but page will be not reloaded. I tryied add some script, but then, system add 12 items to cart.

```
    $('a').click(function (event) 
{ 
   event.preventDefault(); 

   var url = $(this).attr('href');
   $.get(url, function(data) {
     alert(data);
    });

 });
```

Comment: Please explain what is the problem. What you want/expect to get and what happened.

Comment: When I click "add to cart" - page is reload to CART and item is added. I have to change it like this:. Wthen I click "add to cart" - page is not reloaded, but item is added to Cart.  

Simply: I want to set target from "href="" will be perform in background without reload page :)